# Problems with MailCore 2 and MCONNTPFetchOverviewOperation.mm

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mailcore

I am new to Objective-C and Xcode 4.6.3.

I'm trying to configure the MailCore 2 API in Xcode. I followed the instructions [in the README on GitHub](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/blob/master/build-mac/README.md), but it seems like MCONNTPFetchOverviewOperation.mm does not work properly and has given me a bunch of errors.

Comment: If you don't tell us, which problems you have (some examples, plz), nobody will help you here

Comment: How can I give the example when I haven't done anything yet.
also stackoverflow restricting me to add images to my question.
if you give me some hints that how can I add images to my question so it will be great appreciated.

Comment: You said "it seems MCONNTPFetchOverviewOperation.mm does not work properly and has a bunch of error list I've gotten."... So isn't that anything you've tried already? If you haven't done anything yet - this is the wrong platform to ask. Ask google instead.

Comment: I said that already that I have followed all the steps provided by the github  https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/blob/master/build-mac/README.md
but It giving me the error for MCONNTPFetchOverviewOperation